# Jquery select previous element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery and I've had a look through the replies on here but I can't find any specific answers to my question.

I have a (ASP) generated table a snippet of which is:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gv2&#39;,&#39;Select$15&#39;)"
style="color:White;">S</a></td><td style="font-size:XX-Small;">1104</td>
<td style="font-size:XX-Small;">320.20.0116.090</td>
<td style="font-size:XX-Small;">*Not Found*</td>
```

What I'm trying to do is highlight the ***Not Found** text and then disable the preceeding href so the link cannot be clicked.

I have developed the following selector:-

**$('td').highlight('*Not Found*').each(function(){$(this).prev("a").removeAttr("href")});**

The highlight selector works but the removeattr doesn't. Syntax is probably incorrect but any pointers would be very useful.

**Answered:**- This works

```
$("td:contains('*Not Found*')").each(function(){$(this).parent().find('a').removeAttr("href")})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

```
// selects all 'td' elements
$('td').filter(function(){
    // retains only those whose text is precisely '*Not Found*'
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == '*Not Found*';
// moves to the closest (ancestor) 'tr'
// finds the 'a' element within that 'tr' element
// sets the 'href' attribute to be equal to '#'
}).closest('tr').find('a').attr('href','#');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZCueB/).

Alternatively, rather than setting the `href` to `#`, you could just remove the `a` element by unwrapping its contents:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == '*Not Found*';
}).closest('tr').find('a').contents().unwrap();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZCueB/1/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: Excellent. My solution works but this is nicer (and has taught me some new stuff). Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

try `$(this).prev().find("a").removeAttr("href")}`

also removing the link might not work.

try replacing the href with `#`